# How to check whether the photo was taken in landscape or portrait mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm a newbie in Android. I'm trying to make an application with the photo capturing feature inside. The problem is the photo rotation is not right. If I take the photo in landscape mode, it will be good, but in portrait mode the photo rotation will be wrong. My question is: can I check whether the photo is taken in landscape/portrait mode? Because as I checked on the LogCat I can see the tag named "CameraEngine" and it says rotation: 0 or 90. It will be cool if I can get that kind of camera information by code.

Comment: do you want to know just after you capture the photo from camera, or while you pick that image from gallery?

Answer (score 5):

You can compare image width and height:

```
Bitmap bmp = your photo;

if(bmp.getWidth() > bmp.getHeight())
{
   // landscape
}else
{
   // portrait
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot** check in Android if the photo was taken specially with PhoneGape 2.9 and beyond.

Because you have to extract this information from **EXIF property** stored in the taken photo and android doesn't even write out the orientation to this property.

you can refer to this reply to the question bellow for more information :
[canvas drawImage() with photos taken on iphone in landscape are rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221005/canvas-drawimage-with-photos-taken-on-iphone-in-landscape-are-rotated)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. It returns the orientation as an angle (0/90/180/270):

```
private int getOrientation(Uri aUri, ContentResolver aRslv) {
    Cursor _cursor = aRslv.query(aUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
            null, null, null);

    if (_cursor != null) {
        try {

            if (_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return _cursor.getInt(0);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } finally {
            _cursor.close();
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to call it inside the onActivityResult, but the result's always returned 0. Did I do in the right way? please help

Comment: Are you getting a non-null cursor back from the ContentResolver?

Comment: Yep, I got the cursor like this: "android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@405273f0". I also tried to print out the _cursor.getInt(0), it always returns 0.